# Lines and planes in cubic surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm a little bit confused about lines and a planes in cubic surfaces. The definition of a line I was given was the following:

> A line in $\mathbb{P}^3$ is an embedding $\mathbb{P}^1 \subset \mathbb{P}^3$ given by:
> $$[\lambda : \mu] \rightarrow [x_1\lambda + x_2\mu : y_1\lambda + y_2\mu : z_1\lambda + z_2\mu : w_1\lambda + w_2\mu]$$ for $[x_1:y_1:z_1:w_1] \neq [x_2:y_2:z_2:w_2]$

Then in the example of the cubic surface given by $wxz + xy^2+y^3 = 0$, I was told that this contains the *line* $x=y=0$ and the *plane* $x=0$.

My question is why $x=y=0$ is a line and not a plane?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Not in $\mathbb{P}_3$  It's the set of point with homogeneous coordinates $(0,0,z,1)$ which is a line.

Comment: $x=y=0$ is the intersection of the planes $x=0$ and $y=0$. Incidentally, the plane $x=0$ does NOT lie on this cubic surface; plugging the plane into the surface yields $y^3=0$, so actually the plane is tangent to the surface along the line with multiplicity $3$.